# Are "Allow users to view and interact" and "psexec -i" equivalent?

Tags: sccm

I have an application that works when installed (independently of SCCM) using

```
psexec -s -i Install-Application.bat
```

but fails when installed using

```
psexec -s Install-Application.bat
```

The symptom in the latter case is that the UI never appears when the application process is launched.

So far I have always left the "Allow users to view and interact" box unchecked because [that is best practice because of security concerns](https://blog.thesysadmins.co.uk/sccm-2012-allow-end-user-to-run-application-as-administrator.html).  (For this application achieving automated deployment outweighs this particular security concern.)  Indeed installation by the SCCM client fails in the same way as above with "Allow users to view and interact" left unchecked.

Is checking "Allow users to view and interact" equivalent to installing with the `-i` option of `psexec`?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861933/net-gui-not-displaying-in-winpe

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky to test since you need an application that measurably behaves differently when installed

- with and without the `-i` switch of `psexec`, or
- with and without the "Allow users to view and interact" box checked.

So far the only application where I have noticed such behavior is the application "Logitech Options 3.0.77".  I just tested its installation behavior using all four aforementioned variations of `psexec` and SCCM client and options.  Here are the results:

```
Invoke Method | Option          | Result
--------------+-----------------+-------------
psexec        | -s              | fail: No UI
psexec        | -i -s           | success
SCCM Client   | no interact     | fail: No UI
SCCM Client   | allow interact  | success
```

By all indications for "Logitech Options 3.0.77" the `-i` switch of `psexec` is equivalent to checking the "Allow users to view and interact" check box.  Whether this generalizes to other applications remains to be seen.

These results suggest that it is a good starting assumption that if an application only installs correctly with `psexec`'s `-i` option, it will need the "Allow users to view and interact" box checked to install correctly using SCCM.